# How do I write a batch file which will execute another batch file?

Tags: batch-file, scripting

I have a text file which contains the list of some 200 server names and I have a batch file which will provide the output related to the IIS sites hosted on the server.

I have tried sample batch files and didn't work for me.

This is the batch file that I used to get all the iis site information related to the server.

```
(net config workstation | findstr /C:"Full Computer name"
________________________________________
@ipconfig /all | find "IP Address" 
@ipconfig /all | find "IPv4 Address" 
@ipconfig /all | find "Subnet Mask" 
@ipconfig /all | find "Default Gateway" 
@ipconfig /all | find "Host Name" 
@ipconfig /all | find "DNS Suffix Search List" 
@ipconfig /all | find "Physical Address" 
@ipconfig /all | find "DHCP Enabled" 
@ipconfig /all | find "DHCP Server"
_________________________________________
cd c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv
appcmd list site
appcmd list apppool) > c:\IISSiteBindings.txt
```

I need a batch file that will call the text file which contains the list of server names and for each server, the batch needs to execute the above-mentioned script file to get all the information related to the server in a text file format as output.

Comment: To anyone confused about the question, it has absolutely no relationship to the posted batch file code. It is "How do I run a batch script on each server listed one per line in a text file?"

Comment: Just a tip: Have you considered powershell? It's usually significantly less frustrating to do things with it vs .bat files.

Comment: You might want to consider the WMI commandline executable, `WMIC` for this task. Open up a Command Prompt window and enter `wmic /?` to read its usage information. For example, something like this, `WMIC /Node:@Servers.txt /User:Administrator /Password:MyPa55w0rd /Output:Results.log Process Call Create "serverPath\MyBatch.cmd"` could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Inside a batch file, all you need to do to call another batch file is:

```
call batchfile.bat
```

Comment: That i know but how the batch file will read the text file and run the other batch file

Comment: Instead of here if some one calls me to +91-9989056895 so that i can explain easily.

Comment: Offering a more thorough description of what you are trying to do and where the problems are will help too

Comment: @chandu are you really expecting someone to come up to you to request clarification? Well, I thought it is you that needs help with some script, so is it not more logical that you provide as much information as necessary to be able for someone to help you?